# How to check if two types are the same in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm learning Common Lisp and is now trying to replicate C++'s (boost's) `lexical_cast<bool>(string)`. But can't find a way to compare types in CL.

The C++ version looks like this

```cpp
template <typename ret_type>
ret_type lexical_cast(const std::string& val)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<ret_type, bool>)
        return val == "true";
    // Otherwise don't care
}
```

So far I came up with the following Lisp code using `equal` to compare types. I assume this would work as Lisp is indifferent of data and code.

```lisp
(defun lexical_cast(ret_type val)
    (if (equal ret_type #'boolean) (equalp val "true"))
    ; Otherwise don't case
)
```

But SBCL generates error:

```
; in: DEFUN LEXICAL_CAST
;     #'BOOLEAN
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   The function BOOLEAN is undefined, and its name is reserved by ANSI CL so that
;   even if it were defined later, the code doing so would not be portable.
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     BOOLEAN
;   caught 1 WARNING condition
```

Nor `typep` helps as it compares the type of a object against another type. Not directly comparing them. I've search through Lisp tutorials and manuals without success. How should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common Lisp defines [`SUBTYPEP`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_subtpp.htm) to compare types. Using that, you can define a type equality comparison function:

```
(defun type-equal (t1 t2)
  (and (subtypep t1 t2)
       (subtypep t2 t1)))
```

For example, there are different way to encode the `boolean` type, but they cover the same set of values so they are equal:

```
(type-equal '(member t nil) '(or (eql t) (eql nil)))
=> T, T
```

There is also a [`COERCE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_coerce.htm) functions that in a limited way allows to convert a value to another type. This is however not extensible.

#### Simple cast

Let's define first a new condition for cases where we don't know how to cast a value to a target type. To keep things simple, this error has no associated data:

```
(define-condition cast-error (error) ())
```

Then, a rigid but simple definition for `lexical-cast` can be:

```
(defun lexical-cast (return-type value)
  (coerce (cond
            ((type-equal return-type 'boolean)
             (typecase value
               (string (string= value "true"))
               (real (/= value 0))
               (t (error 'cast-error))))
            ((subtypep return-type 'real)
             (typecase value
               (string (read-from-string value))
               (boolean (if value 1 0))
               (t (error 'cast-error))))
            (t
             (error 'cast-error)))
          return-type))
```

I wrap the `cond` form in a `coerce` form to check the inner result is of the appropriate return-type. This helps detect implementation errors.

The inner form performs multiple-dispatch on the return type (`cond`) and on the value's type (`typecase`s). You can for example convert from a string to a boolean:

```
(lexical-cast '(member t nil) "true")
T
```

Assuming we follow the C convention of 0 being false, here is a cast from a number (notice that the boolean type is expressed differently):

```
(lexical-cast '(or (eql t) (eql nil)) 0)
NIL
```

Note also that Common Lisp allows you to define ranges. Here we have an error because reading from the string gives a value outside of the excepted range (careful: reading from a string can be unsafe for some inputs, but this is out of scope here).

```
(lexical-cast '(integer 0 10) "50")
;; error from COERCE

(lexical-cast '(integer 0 10) "5")
5
```

Here is another example, casting to a subtype of reals from a boolean:

```
(lexical-cast 'bit t)
1
```

#### Extensible cast

In order to have a generic extensible lexical cast, like [`PPRINT-DISPATCH`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_ppr_di.htm), you would need to maintain of table of conversion functions for different types, while ensuring you always select the closest type matching the return-type.

A very simplified way to do that would be to define individual generic conversion functions for some dedicated return types:

```
;; can be extended for other classes of values
(defgeneric cast-to-boolean (value)
  (:method ((v symbol))  v)
  (:method ((v integer)) (eql v 1))
  (:method ((v string))  (string= v "true")))
```

Then, you maintain a mapping from types to conversion functions:

```
;; usually this is hidden behind user-friendly macros

(defvar *type-cast* nil)  

;; this could be written instead (set-cast 'boolean #'cast-to-boolean)
;; for example, but here we just set the list directly.

(setf *type-cast*
      (acons 'boolean #'cast-to-boolean *type-cast*))
```

Then, you have a single cast function that looks up the first type that is equal to the return-type, and call the associated function:

```
(defun gen-type-cast (return-type value)
  (let ((f (assoc return-type *type-cast* :test #'type-equal)))
    (if f (funcall (cdr f) value) (error 'cast-error))))
```

For example:

```
(gen-type-cast '(member t nil) "true")
T
```

#### See also

The [**`lisp-types`**](https://gitlab.lrde.epita.fr/jnewton/regular-type-expression/-/tree/cl-robdd/lisp-types) system can be helpful to analyze and simplify type expressions.

Answer (score 1):

My bad. I found the issue right after posting the question. The # shouldn't be there

```lisp
(defun lexical_cast(ret_type val)
    (if (equal ret_type 'boolean) (equalp val "true"))
    ; Otherwise don't case
)
```